# SharePoint hierarchical workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, custom-list

I have a SharePoint list. If a new item is inserted, then I need a hierarchical workflow to approve it.

I mean, each employee's manager will be different. If an employee inserted an item to this list from HR department then it should approve from HR department manager, if an employee inserted an item to this list from finance department then it should approve from finance department manager, and so on.

So how we can achieve this type of workflow. I am using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you could use an OOTB [approval workflow](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/all-about-approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742) (you'll find lots of other info on approval workflows too), but you'd have to modify it in order to add the conditions you need e.g. if Accounts, send to Accounts Manager for approval.

Perhaps you could use an Approvers group with all of the managers included.  Then, perhaps your List items could be named in such a way that it is clear who has to approve the item.  For instance call the item "Acc-001-*add your description here*" for an Accounts item that hte Accounts manager has to approve.  Otherwise any manager could approve something that they are not responsible for.

You can set the completion conditions of the approval to be that it is approved if one manager approves the item.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Tally. But my requirement is, workflow should go to respective manager/supervisor only.

Comment: Well, as I said in my Answer, if you want to use an OOTB approval workflow...you'd have to modify it in order to add in the conditions you need.  Or, if you want, you can create separate Lists - one per manager.